# Sublime MarkdownEditing plugin color scheme and line numbers

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I like to utilize Markdown for a lot of the text that I write. To that end I wanted to try out the [MarkdownEditing plugin for Sublime Text 3](http://sublimetext-markdown.github.io/MarkdownEditing/), but am having some user experience issues:

1. I cannot figure out how to change the color scheme such that it affects the MarkdownEditing syntax editor. Changes to `.Packages\User\Preferences.sublime-settings` do not effect display settings when in this syntax highlighting mode. However, those changes are reflected in other tabs. How do I change the color scheme when making use of the MarkdownEditing syntax highlighting?
2. How do I turn on line numbers when making use of this syntax plugin?

[image: screenshot of drab grey]

Comment: As I've done in the past, +1 for MSPaint-ish handwriting. I, sadly, have nothing constructive to add.

Comment: This is documented in the [configuration section](https://github.com/SublimeText-Markdown/MarkdownEditing#configuration). Please help developers by reading them.

Comment: @maliayas I did read the documentation section and the instructions didn't work hence the question here. I'm big on helping myself before asking others.

Comment: @ahsteele Ok, no problem. If you see something to improve in the docs, PR welcome.

Answer (score 15):

TL;DR

If you are using Markdown GFM syntax, open/create "Data/Packages/User/Markdown.sublime-settings" and add:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/your/custom.tmTheme",
    "line_numbers": true
}
```

---

See menu: `Preferences > Package Settings > MarkdownEditing`.

There are 3 different settings there for 3 different syntaxes. First check what "default" settings does and then undo it in "user" settings.

Comment: The most helpful answer by far, thanks!
While even more helpful it would have been not to have this issue in first place, i.e. showing no line numbers should have not been the default setting.

Comment: Thanks. I guess most of the people don't expect line numbers for prose. For those who do, the setting is actually quite simple.

Comment: I struggle to understand why would anyone object to see the line numbers? It is a valuable information. Especially for the technical users of Sublime with its numerous reporting and automating tools. As you can also see from the numbers of upvotes and viewings of this question. The customization feels actually intimidating with 5 different files while most packages have only one. And why is this setting under GFM?

Comment: Similar to why we don't use line numbers in Word. However it's _very_ easy to enable it if anyone needs it. The setting exists for all the 3 flavours, not only GFM. Number of upvotes to this question (11) doesn't serve as a poll as it speaks only for one side. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Hm... with separate settings for GFM and non-GFM, how will Sublime know which one is my `md` file?
Word is not designed for technical users. Sublime is.
Also m$oft products are not exactly masterpieces of design :)
Take it from Linus Torvalds: https://www.azquotes.com/quote/296073.
The package is awesome otherwise!

Comment: You effectively tell Sublime which one to pick, once, and then it opens all `.md` files with that setting. I agree with you about MS (especially Excel is a terrible design :) ). But the thing with Word (no line numbers) applies to other text processing programs as well. Anyway, so this is the rationale behind Markdown Editing's behaviour. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

To stop the MarkdownEditing package from overriding your color scheme on Markdown files:

1. Open `Preferences > Settings - User`
2. Find your `color_scheme` line - e.g. it looks like
   `"color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme",`
3. Copy the entire line
4. Open `Preferences > Package Settings > Markdown Editing > Markdown GFM Settings - Default`
5. Comment out the other `color_scheme` lines by adding `//` in front of them
6. Paste your line instead
7. Save the file

Markdown files will now use your regular color scheme rather than using their own scheme just for `.md` files.

If you get an error about "Error trying to parse settings", make sure your line ends with a `,` if there are lines below it, and does *not* end with `,` if it is the last line.

Comment: this method worked most reliably. And worked very very well with the range of color schemes on https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Colorsublime

Comment: sublime didn't allow me to change the `Markdown GFM Settings - Default`. So I used @maliayas answer to change in the User file.

Answer (score 3):

This was one of the most annoying things about this plugin when I installed it a while back, so I promptly got rid of it. However, before doing so, I figured out how to solve your problems. First, since you're using ST3, you'll need to install the quite-useful [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin. Open the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on Windows), type in ***`prv`*** to bring up the `PackageResourceViewer` options, and select `Extract Package`. Scroll down and select `MarkdownEditing`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and you're all set. You can now open `Packages/MarkdownEditing` (`Packages` should be in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3`, also available by selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**) in the sidebar and browse through all the different `.sublime-settings` files for the different syntaxes and for the main plugin, changing things as you want. The syntax-specific files use all the same options found in **`Preferences -> Settings-Default`**, so for example you can set `"line_numbers": true` to turn line numbering back on, and change the value of `"color_scheme"` to your preferred value.

Comment: Did you find a plugin that you preferred for Markdown syntax highlighting? I'm not wedded to this plugin by any means. ;-)

Comment: @ahsteele I've found that [this syntax](https://gist.github.com/MattDMo/95aa1c6951163e94efb7) works best for me, paired with my [Neon Color Scheme](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme). The syntax is from [knockdown](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/knockdown), modified somewhat (mostly removing the regex comments so it translates well into a `.YAML-tmLanguage` file, and fixing a thing or two).

Answer (score 0):

I had another packaged named Markdownlight which was overriding the color scheme. I had to uninstall it before the color_scheme in the MarkdownEditing user settings took affect.